# SQL Count, Sum and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an SQL statement to query a table to count quantity of a product, sum the cost and group by item number and for some reason, i'm having a difficult time.

Here is a sample data file:

```
**MAKE    MODEL   COST**
Canon   C100    125
HP      H100    30
HP      H100    30
HP      H100    30
Canon   C100    150
Xerox   X100    125
Xerox   X100    125
Xerox   X200    125
```

The results i'm looking for would look like this:

```
**Model Qty Cost**
C100    2   275
H100    3   90
X100    2   250
X200    1   125
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you have tried.  This seems like a really simple `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `SELECT Model, COUNT(*) AS Qty, SUM(Cost) AS Cost FROM yourTable GROUP BY Model`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Make him work for it.

Comment: Wow! I was using something much more complicated with sub-queries however your solution works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this answer. This is very basic level `Aggregate` functionality. Can you please search on the net, you'll get the answer easily:

```
SELECT MODEL
    ,COUNT(1) AS QTY
    ,SUM(COST) AS COST 
FROM [Table] GROUP BY MODEL
```